# Sum Multiple Calculations From Multiple Columns of One Row Into Single Cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a leaderboard style spreadsheet where for every task someone has achieved:
- they get a point in one of the columns (column E, F, G, H, I , J, K, L),
- that point is multiplied by the column value (row 2 - E2, F2, G2, H2, I2 , J2, K2, L2 value),
- and the sum of all those, is equal to the users score

This works for **row 5** user:
=SUM(E5*E2 + F5*F2 + G5*G2 + H5*H2 + I5*I2 + J5*J2 + K5*K2 + L5*L2)

This works for **row 6** user:
=SUM(E6*E2 + F6*F2 + G6*G2 + H6*H2 + I6*I2 + J6*J2 + K6*K2 + L6*L2)

What is a better way to do this because I will need to add new columns (things worth points) and new users - I think there must be a better way then to write each of these by hand. There's over 60 users now and over 15 point opportunities and growing.

Example:

`| User        | Total Score | task1 | task2 | task3 | task4 | task5 | task6 |
| Point Value |             | 2     | 3     | 5     | 1     | 0.5   | 9     |
| User5       |  12         | 1     | 0     | 2     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| User6       |  6.5        | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 3     | 0     |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT($E$2:$L$2,$E5:$L5)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried =SUMPRODUCT before but didn't pair it with the $ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Erase B:B column(Total points column):

B3:

```
=MMULT(E3:L4,TRANSPOSE(E2:L2))
```

Comment: @Max Thanks. It seems Excel could also do this. But they need to select all B3:B4 and enter formula and CTRL SHIFT ENTER. But I'm not sure.